# Using Azure Media Services with on-prem assets

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

Is it possible to stream on-premises media files through Azure Media Services without storing them in the cloud?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. AMS uses blob storage as the source for assets that are being encoded and streamed. From a performance perspective this approach makes sense as well.

Note that the uploaded content is protected using storage protection and access policies.